# Trying to create an 'eye doctor exam'-like program (or find an already existing one)

Tags: list, input, printing, rank

I don't even know where to start with describing this question.

I listen to a lot of music, and I've found that when trying to 'rank' all these albums, it can be difficult unless you go down the list and compare them two at a time (which one is better x or y). Kind of like how at the optometrist you're asked "Which looks better, one or two?"

What I'm trying to do is either find an already existing program or get the code for a program that would:

a) allow you to input a large list of items
b) go down the line and compare them two at a time, logging your response for each choice
c) print out a list of your final 'results', showing which one you ranked the highest through your choices in a numbered list.

I have virtually no experience coding, and this question/request is far too bulky for a google search, so now I'm here.

Comment: Any languages you're comfortable with? And are you try to do thing like spotify?

Comment: early 2000's html lol, so no. And no, I'm trying to make it where you can individually input each item manually, so once you have the list compiled it starts running the comparisons.

Comment: hahahah , nothing looks good

Comment: So I have a couple of inputs, on what basis am I supposed to run comparison?

Comment: What kind of inputs are we talking here? Scores with name or something?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but here's what I mean: https://puu.sh/x23im/c2c6ae1348.png

Comment: Easy game, what language you prefer? What operating system do you use?

Comment: Windows 10, and it can be any language as long as it's something I could open and use without too much hassle.

Comment: Python is what i am going for , you may have to wait for a while like half hour or less , you good with that?

Comment: While i am writing this code , install python on your computer

Comment: Thank you! I'll install python now.

Comment: Hey , it'll take more time than expected, but i'll make sure that i deliver it! You can mail me at ubdussamad[at the rate]gmail , so i can notify you there.

Comment: Sounds good! Thank you for your help, and I'll email you shortly.

Comment: Download python 3 at the following link. https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-362/
Next you need to add the python install to your system environmental path variable. https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path finally open notepad copy paste the script from my answer and save it to your desktop as comparisons.py open cmd, cd to desktop and finally run `python comparisons.py`

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three problems that you need to solve here.

1. Gather a list from a user.
2. Generate an exhaustive list of pairwise combinations from the list.
3. Gather preference for each pair from the user.
4. Use the preference for each pair to impose an order on the list.

The first 3 problems are fairly simple however the 4th problem is a topic of much mathematical discussion and publication.

> The following is a bare bones script for **python3**.

```
#!/bin/python3
# Part 1 get the list from the user.

items = []
item = "..."
while(item!=""):
    item = input("enter item name or type enter to continue:")
    if(item!=""):
        items.append(item)

# Part 2 make combinations from list

def combinations(aList):
    done = []
    result = []
    for k in aList:
        done.append(k)
        for k2 in aList:
            if not(k2 in done):
               result.append((k,k2)) 
    return(result)

toRank = combinations(items)

# Part 3 get rankings for combinations 

preferences = {}
for k in toRank:
    choice = "2"
    while not(choice in ["0","1"]):
        choice = input("0:"+k[0]+"\t"+"1:"+k[1]+"\n")
    preferences[k] = choice 

# Part 4 rank list based on rankings
# This part is not straight forward but for the purposes of the example
# we will simply put things in order based on how many times they were 
# chosen in a head on head comparison.

wins = {k:0 for k in items}

for k in preferences:   
    wins[k[int(preferences[k])]]+=1

from operator import itemgetter
rankedList = sorted(wins.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
rankedList.reverse()

#Print The final result
resultText = ""
for k in rankedList:
    resultText+=str(k)+"\n"

with open("restultFile.txt","w") as outFile:
    outFile.write(resultText[:-1])
```

This is the **minimum viable product**. It is completely bare bones however it's existence  permits early users to identify what specifications should be incorporated into the next generation of the product. Writing code is all about defining obtainable increments. Start small and build up.

If you are interested in learning to program I would recommend that you make your first objective "hello world" (write a program that puts the text "hello world" on the screen) and while the provided example is in python3 your existing experience in HTML might make JS a best language for you to start learning.

Edit: The output is printed to a file "restultFile.txt" instead of being printed to the terminal.

Comment: This works great! I can see what you meant by bare bones, and when you add a lot of items in the list it can be pretty lengthy to go through the whole process, but in this case that's actually exactly what I need! However, I still don't know exactly how to print out the finished result, how would you do this?

Comment: Similar to my approach,   a neater version to be honest!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I enter the names of everything to use in the comparison, take the test, and then as soon as it's over the program closes. What do I do after that happens to find the results?

Comment: Lol that's interesting. If you run the program from cmd the results should be printed on the terminal... I'll add a couple lines so the output writes to a file.

Answer (score 0):

There you go,

```
#Written for user ECHtoplasm
# Author: Ubdussmad <mailto:ubdussmad@gmail.com>
import operator
data = []
parent = dict()


def take_inputs():
    stop = False
    while stop == False:
        z=raw_input('Enter the name of the album or enter 0 if finished: ')
        if z == '0':
            stop=True
        else:
            data.append(z)
            parent[z] = 0

def compare(data):
    for i in data:
        temp = data[:]
        temp.remove(i)
        for j in temp:
            z=raw_input('Is album  %s better than album %s (y/n): '% (i,j))
            if z.lower() == 'y':parent[i] += 1

#This loop runs for len(data)^2 - len(data)
def main():
    take_inputs()
    compare(data)
    ranks = sorted(parent.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    print '\n ------Rankings in ascending order are...-------'
    for i in ranks:
        print i[0]
main()
```

It's a bit cleaner version and uses Python2.7 , the module used is 'built in' and it's a bit diffrent approach compared to other answers but still uses the same concept!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be launching. Am I supposed to do the same thing as the other person's answer and paste it into notepad, saving as a XXX.py file?

Comment: yeah , paste it in notepad and then save it as file.py

Comment: run it using python file.py

Comment: what python version are you using?